# Unix perl match string and delete line

Tags: perl

Im using perl to remove a string from a file, it is removing the string from file,  But the actual line is not getting deleted, Due to which the next insert to the files are getting written over next line.

Perl command used:

```
host=ABC1234
perl -lpi -e "s/$host//g" /tmp/exclude_list
```

output:

```
ABC1234
```

Comment: You are replacing a substring on each line in the file. Do you want to delete the whole line?

Comment: @Kusalananda i want delete the whole line .. If you have options with awk also i can try.

Comment: A already wrote an answer.

Comment: `grep -v` is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
cp /tmp/exclude_list /tmp/exclude_list.tmp
grep -Fx -v -e "$host" /tmp/exclude_list.tmp >/tmp/exclude_list
rm /tmp/exclude_list.tmp
```

you would remove each line that *exactly* matches the string in `$host`.  Change `-Fx` to just `-F` to remove any line that *contains* the string.  Don't use `-F` if you want to use `$host` as a regular expression.

Or with Perl:

```
perl -i -sn -e 'print unless /$host/' -- -host="$host" /tmp/exclude_list
```

The options used with `perl` here is `-i` for in-place editing, `-s` to allow Perl to instantiate the `$host` Perl variable from the command line, and `-n` to only print explicitly from within the implicit loop that Perl provides around the code.  The `-e` takes the actual code as the argument.

The Perl code would remove all lines that does not match the regular expression `$host`.

To use `$host` as a *string*:

```
perl -i -sn -e 'print unless index($_, $host) >= 0' -- -host="$host" /tmp/exclude_list
```

Comment: sed -i is not working on AIX Korn Shell.  Thanks for the quick solution

Comment: @kusalananda, sometimes "!..." expands for bash history. Perhaps `"/host/ or print"`

Comment: @JJoao Thanks, I'm not on `bash` so I didn't think about that. (and the user is in `ksh` anyway)

Comment: You can pass a shell variable into perl like this: `perl -sne '/$host/ || print' -- -host="$host" /tmp/exclude_list` -- that allows you to use single quotes around the perl script. `-s` enables something like awk's `-v`. You need `--` to signal to perl that the command line options to the perl executable are finished, and the other options can be picked up by the script body.

Comment: one last comment: if we're sure that $host is the only text on the line, then add the `-l` option (to auto strip/add newline) and `print unless $_ eq $host`

Comment: @Kusalananda   could you provide the perl one liner for the same to insert the text on the same file